# How to print out a decimal number as octal number using setiosflags in C++

Tags: c++, manipulators

I have tried this

```
cout. setf(ios::oct, ios::basefield) ;
cout << 79 << endl;
```

It works but
using manipulator setiosflags

```
cout << setiosflags (ios::oct) << 79 << endl;
```

It doesn't work, there's still 79 printed at the screen.
Although I heard `setiosflags` is the alternative of `setf.

Then how to print out the decimal number as octal number using `setiosflags`?

Comment: what is the meaning of "it doesn't work" ? If you get compiler errors you have to include them in the question

Comment: I've changed my mind and voted to reopen the question. I think it's useful for future research about the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the flags first using the [std::resetiosflags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/resetiosflags):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  int x = 42;
  std::cout << std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::dec)
            << std::setiosflags(std::ios_base::hex | std::ios_base::showbase)
            << x;
}
```

The `| std::ios_base::showbase` part is optional.

Comment: Can you briefly explain @Ron  why do we need to use resetiosflags

Answer (score 6):

Keep It Simple and Stupid (or shortly [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)):

```
std::cout << std::oct << 79 << std::endl;
```

[`std::oct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) is a syntactic sugar for `str.setf(std::ios_base::oct, std::ios_base::basefield)`, which (as you noticed) is one of the ways to force stream to print integral values in octal notation.

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MM2oiq4B2UeUN2WW)

Answer (score 0):

you can use also

```
 printf("%o",79);
```

Comment: The OP clearly asks about c++ I/O manipulators. Your answer doesn't cover that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ With that approach, my answer should be downvoted as well, because it doesn't use `std::setiosflags`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen But your answer shows a way how to use I/O manipulators.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this your issue will be resolve.
cout << hex << 79;
cout << oct << 79;